# Re-size page size in existing pdf using itext

Tags: java, itext, itextpdf

I am using following code to create new document from existing pdf.

I want to shrink all pages(re-size) of existing pdf in new generated pdf.

Code i am using:

```
public void resize() throws IOException, DocumentException {

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("D:/test/scaned4.pdf");
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.LEGAL, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        System.out.println(reader.isTampered());

        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(
                "D:/test/result.pdf"));
        document.open();
        PdfImportedPage page;
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            page = copy.getImportedPage(reader, i);
            copy.addPage(page);

        }
        reader.close();
        document.close();

}
```

There is any way to **shrink imported page** before add to new document.

Comment: The `Pdf*Copy*` family of classes are the classes of choice if you want to copy existing material as is with as completely as possible. If you want to manipulate the page, importing it into a `PdfWriter` is appropriate, and adding an imported page template to a `PdfWriter` allows you to scale it, rotate it, etc.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. can you provide sample code that help me to scale page.

Comment: The [NUpTool](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=115) (a sample putting *n* scaled down pages of some document onto one page of the target document) shows how to do that. The scaling by `factor` is done in `cb.addTemplate(page, factor, 0, 0, factor, offsetX, offsetY);`.

Comment: Thanks once again. can i use addTemplate(...) if i use PdfCopy as you have suggested and how?.

Comment: *can i use addTemplate(...) if i use PdfCopy* - I doubt that works as intended. `PdfCopy` is designed for copying pages unchanged, but you want to change it (you want to scale it down). Just use a `PdfWriter` as the [NUpTool](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=115) does.

Comment: i also want page unchanged except scale it down top and bottom for adding header and footer.